# Nvidia GeForce GT 525M tearing on Ubuntu 16.04 GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a Dell Inspiron One 2320 pc with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 in dualboot. 
When i boot into Windows, everything works smooth.
In Linux, xserver-xorg-video-nouveau driver is less tearing, but it is very slow. All nvidia binary drivers, even from PPA drive me crazy with their tearing, but they are really fast.
**Please help me! I still want to use Linux!**

Comment: Try closed-source driver: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia